# Identity index for NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a flat NumPy array `a` and want to define an index array `i` to index `a` with and thus obtain `a` again by `a[i]`.

I tried

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2]).reshape(-1)
i = True
```

But this does not preserve shape: `a[i]` has shape `(1, 2)` while `a` has shape `(2,)`.

I know I could reshape `a[i]` or use `i = np.full_like(a, True, dtype=bool)`. I want neither: The reshape is unnecessary if `i` is per some conditional definition sometimes not plain `True` but a boolean array matching the shape of `a`. The second approach means I need different `i`s for doing this on arrays of different shapes.

So... is there something build-in in NumPy to just get the array back when used as index?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "define an index array i to index a with and thus obtain a again by a[i]." Could you please explain?

Comment: @ShambhavGautam what's unclear? Find object `i` such that for `b = a[i]`, the following are true: `b.shape == a.shape` and `(b == a).all(None)`

Comment: `reshape (-1)` does absolutely nothing

Comment: It does: `a[True].reshape(-1).shape` has same shape as `a`. Or were you not refering to the question?

Comment: `a[True]` just adds a initial dimension, like `a[np.newaxis]`.  This indexing isn't well documented.  `a[False]` also adds an initial dimension, but of size 0!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy can not preserve the shape of a boolean masked result because it may be ragged. When you pass in a single boolean scalar, things get special-case weird.

You must therefore use a fancy index. With a fancy index, the shape of the result is exactly the shape of the index. For a 1-D array the following is fine:

```
i = np.arange(a.size)
```

For more dimensions, you'll want to create a full indexing tuple, using [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) for example. The elements of the tuple can broadcast to the final desired shape, so you can use `sparse=True`:

```
i = np.indices(a.shape, sparse=True)
```

If you want `i` to be a numpy array, you can set `sparse=False`, in which case `i` will be of shape `(a.ndim, *a.shape)`.

If you want to cheat, you can use slices. `slice(None)` is the object representing the literal index `:`:

```
i = (slice(None),) * a.ndim
```

Or just index the first dimension only, which returns the entire array:

```
i = slice(None)
```

Or if you're feeling really lazy, use `Ellipsis` directly. This is the object that stands for the literal `...`, meaning `:, :,` etc, as many times as necessary:

```
i = Ellipsis
```

Going back to the boolean mask option, you *can* use it for the same effect if you create a separate array for each dimension:

```
i = tuple(np.ones(k, dtype=bool) for k in a.shape)
```

You could save some memory by only allocating the largest shape and creating views:

```
s = np.ones(max(a.shape), dtype=bool)
i = tuple(s[:k] for k in a.shape)
```

Comment: `Ellipsis` is exactly what I was looking for, as it works the same on arrays of any shape as opposed to using `np.indices` and it certainly will not create a big indexing array either, altough I'm not sure if a boolean index array full of just `True` will ever be created in RAM.

Comment: @Christoph90. All these options are functionally the same. I don't know what you mean by "as opposed to np.indices" If you want boolean indexing, you can create an independent selection for each dimension to get the shape you want too. The total size will be `sum(a.shape)`, which is generally quite manageable

Comment: I meant that you had to explicitly use `a` in constructing the index array in your code that uses `np.indices`. So you could not use that index array for arrays of different shape then `a`.

Comment: @Christoph90. I see. In that case `Ellipsis` is indeed your best option.